# Highlight correct and wrong answer when radio button selected in quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a multiple choice quiz script that uses radio buttons. I wanted to add a feature where when the radio button is selected it checks that if correct answer is chosen then the chose radio button is highlighted green. if the wrong answer is chosen the chosen radio button is highlighted as red and also the correct answer is highlighted as green. then the submit button is enabled.

when i click on the submit button it goes to the next question and process repeated till the quiz is over. The problem is the the highlighting only works after the submit button is clicked. and also the quiz stops working from the second question. How do i Fix this? I have included the jsfiddle and code below. Can some one help with this.

```
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    ["What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B"],
    ["What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C"],
    ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
    ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C"]
];
function _(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion() {
    test = _("test");
    if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='A'id='choA'> <label for='choA'>" + chA + "</label><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='B'id='choB'> <label for='choB'>" + chB + "</label><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='C'id='choC'> <label for='choC'>" + chC + "</label><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()' disabled='disabled' id='choiceSubmit'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {
    debugger;
    if ($("#test input:checked").val() == questions[pos][4]) {
        // correct question clicked
        $("#test input:checked+label").css("background-color", "green");
        correct++;
    }
    else {
        // wrong question clicked
        $("#test input:checked+label").css("background-color", "red");
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        pos++;
        renderQuestion();
    }, 1000);
}

$("document").ready(function () {
    renderQuestion();
    var choiceClicked = false;

    if (!choiceClicked) {
        $("#test input").change(function () {
            choiceClicked = true;
            $("#choiceSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");

        });
    }


});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/n59y2qaa/1/

Comment: I assume this isn't a very serious quiz? Because a clever / tech-savvy user can easily cheat by doing a View Source on the page

Comment: Have in mind that by showing highlight before the submit button click,  the user can press an answer and if sees that's it's red=wrong can then choose the correct answer and then press the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's it https://jsfiddle.net/n59y2qaa/12/

- the highlighting only works after the submit button is clicked

That's because `checkAnswer()` which does the highlights doesn't get called when you click/change the radio buttons.

- the  quiz stops working from the second quest

That's because after submit is pressed you bring new radiobuttons to the document, so you have to set `$("#test input").change(function () {})` for them too.

```css
div#test {
            border: #000 1px solid;
            padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
        }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
    var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
    var questions = [
        ["What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B"],
        ["What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C"],
        ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
        ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C"]
    ];
    function _(x) {
        return document.getElementById(x);
    }
    function renderQuestion() {
        test = _("test");
        if (pos >= questions.length) {
            test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
            _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
            pos = 0;
            correct = 0;
            return false;
        }
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;
        question = questions[pos][0];
        chA = questions[pos][1];
        chB = questions[pos][2];
        chC = questions[pos][3];
        test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
        test.innerHTML += "<input  onclick='checkAnswer()'  type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='A'id='choA'> <label for='choA'>" + chA + "</label><br>";
        test.innerHTML += "<input  onclick='checkAnswer()'  type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='B'id='choB'> <label for='choB'>" + chB + "</label><br>";
        test.innerHTML += "<input  onclick='checkAnswer()'  type='radio' class='choice' name='choices' value='C'id='choC'> <label for='choC'>" + chC + "</label><br>";
        test.innerHTML += "<button  onclick='nextAnswer()' disabled='disabled' id='choiceSubmit'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }

    function checkAnswer() {
        choiceClicked = true;
        $("#choiceSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#test label").css("background-color", "transparent");
        if ($("#test input:checked").val() == questions[pos][4]) {
            // correct question clicked
            $("#test input:checked+label").css("background-color", "green");
            correct++;
        }
        else {
            // wrong question clicked
            $("#test input:checked+label").css("background-color", "red");
        }
    }
    function nextAnswer(){
        setTimeout(function () {
            pos++;
            renderQuestion();
        }, 1000);    
    }
    $("document").ready(function () {
        renderQuestion();
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: wow... thanks... just one more clarification... what if when select the wrong answer and i want to highlight the correct answer as well as the selected wrong answer... How should it be done...

Comment: @Eunice when should this be done? Only when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: when the radio button is clicked it highlight the wrong answer then

Comment: Just add `$('#test input[value="'+questions[pos]4]+'"]').next().css("background-color", "green");` when wrong question clicked.

Comment: @EuniceDhivya, please remember to always upvote the helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding checkAnswer() to onclick event it is not binding when elements are dynamically created.So better to use something like

$("document").ready(function () {

```
    renderQuestion();
    var choiceClicked = false;

    $(document).on("click","#choiceSubmit",function(){
        checkAnswer();
    })

    $(document).on("click","input[type=radio][name=choices]",function(){

      $("#choiceSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
    })    
});
```

checkAnswer() method should be modified to

```
 function checkAnswer() {
    debugger;
    if ($("#test input:checked").val() == questions[pos][4]) {
        // correct question clicked

        console.log($("#test input:checked").val())
       $("#test input:checked+label").addClass('green-background')
        $("#test input:checked").addClass('green-background')
        correct++;
    }
    else {
        // wrong question clicked
        $("#test input:checked+label").addClass('red-background')
        $("#test input:checked").addClass('red-background')
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        pos++;
        renderQuestion();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Finally the css to do the trick are below:

```
div#test{
  border: #000 1px solid;
  padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
    }

input[type='radio']:checked:before {
  background:red;
}


input[type='radio'] {
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid darkgray;
  border-radius:50%;   
  outline:none;    
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px gray inset;
}

input[type='radio']:hover {
  box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px orange inset;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:60%;
  height:60%;
  margin: 20% auto;    
  border-radius:50%;    
}
.green-background{
  background-color: green;
}
.red-background{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/g8ycw0gw/2/
Hope this helps! cheers!!